# Center arbitrary image horizontally

Tags: html, css, image, centering

Why is it so difficult (or as one answer said, "It is not possible.") to center an arbitrary image horizontally? I have had centralized images working for several years; suddenly they sit obstinately at the left. Has there been some recent change in CSS that causes this?

I expect the code below, modified from the CSS DIY, to work, but it does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
img { display:block; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Thumbnail Images</h2>
<p>  ...  </p>

<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
<img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" 
width=15% > 
</div>

</body></html>
```

I realize that scaling an image by percent width is (for no known) reason disallowed, but Jukka advised me to use it anyway, because it works in all browsers I have tried and does exactly what I want, which is to maintain image size proportional to page width. If I float the image right or left it works fine, and I can run a caption alongside the image, but the obvious 'margin : 0 auto;' fails, for no good reason I can see.

Comment: Give `margin:0 auto` to `img` tag not to div tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Margin : Auto**

You can set the margin property to auto to horizontally center the element within its container.

The element will then take up the specified width, and the remaining space will be split equally between the left and right margins

**Add**

```css
img { 
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Thumbnail Images</h2>
<p>  ...  </p>

<div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="Paris"  > 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the styles

```
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

To your `img` element

Comment: The crucial requirement which I had overlooked was the 'display: block;' step. After that, 'margin: 0 auto;' behaves as expected.The <div> is optional.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width:100%;background:skyblue;">
  <img style='display:block;width:25%;margin:0 auto;' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQvl0jMbupgXjeP66hak-u3uwUPcqI3Ovx7zqiWkVhav2V8FjeY1A'/>
</div>
```